# Is there a generic spring-data Exception class to handle exceptions thrown in the repo layer?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-data

I'm using spring-data-jpa to read/write to my DB.  I've read through the documentation for spring-data and the one thing that I can't seem to locate is how it handles exceptions.

I am looking to catch any type of exception thrown by a repo action.  Is there a way of doing this short of just wrapping the individual repo action in a try/catch and catching any RuntimeException?  I'd rather avoid that as that is an even larger catch-all than I'd like.

Does spring-data wrap all exceptions in its own SpringDataException() or something similar?  I've looked through the spring-data-commons jar as well as the spring-data-jpa jar and didn't find anything applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does spring-data wrap all exceptions in its own SpringDataException() or something similar

Yes, sort of. spring-data(-jpa) enable exception translation from JPA exceptions to Spring’s [DataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html) hierarchy:

**From spring-data-jpa reference implementation:**

> ...Beyond that, it activates persistence exception translation for all beans annotated with @Repository to let exceptions being thrown by the JPA persistence providers be converted into Spring’s DataAccessException hierarchy.

**From Spring reference implementation:**

> Spring provides a convenient translation from technology-specific exceptions like SQLException to its own exception class hierarchy with the DataAccessException as the root exception. These exceptions wrap the original exception so there is never any risk that one might lose any information as to what might have gone wrong...

For more [read about Spring DAO support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't looked through the Spring framework docs; I was concentrating on the Spring-Data ones specifically.  However what do you mean by "Yes, sort of"?

Comment: Well, Its not sort of, but yes. I wrote sort of because I didnt know what you expect. For example there is general purpose exception for data integrity constraint violation, but you cant distiguish between primary key and other unique constraint, unless you examine and inspect the exception yourself